# Is there a way for a column to keep a running total of all columns that precede it?

Tags: r

If I have a data frame where I am adding columns, and I would like one column to sum them up.  I will not know the names of the columns ahead of time, so I guess I would need some kind of function that would count the number of columns and then sum them up.

If my data is like this:

```
w=1:10
x=11:20
z=data.frame(w,x)
```

I would like the total for `z$w` and `z$x`.  But then if I were to add `z$y`, I would like to have that incorporated into the sum as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider not adding a column for the sum, and just call `rowSums(z)` whenever you need it. That removes the hassle of having to update the column whenever you modify your data.frame.

Now if that's really what you want, here is a little function that will update the sum and always keep it as the last column. You'll have to run it every time you make a change to your data.frame:

```
> refresh.total <- function(df) {
+     df$total <- NULL
+     df$total <- rowSums(df)
+     return(df)
+ }
> 
> z <- refresh.total(z)
> z
    w  x total
1   1 11    12
2   2 12    14
3   3 13    16
4   4 14    18
5   5 15    20
6   6 16    22
7   7 17    24
8   8 18    26
9   9 19    28
10 10 20    30
> 
> z$y <- 2:11
> z <- refresh.total(z)
> z
    w  x  y total
1   1 11  2    14
2   2 12  3    17
3   3 13  4    20
4   4 14  5    23
5   5 15  6    26
6   6 16  7    29
7   7 17  8    32
8   8 18  9    35
9   9 19 10    38
10 10 20 11    41
```

Answer (score 1):

After you've finished adding in all the columns, you can do:

```
z$total <- rowSums(z)
```